# Problem while saving the Excel template 2003 in Excel 2007 in c# (Vsto)

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, vba

I have developed office project in 2003 (Excel template).All features are working fine but when file is saved in Excel 2007 the following Error is generated:

Errors where detected while saving "File name".Microsoft office excel may be able to save the file by removing or repairing some features.To make the repairs in new file Click on Continue.To cancel saving the file click Cancel

Is there any solution to handle or remove this error?

Your help is appreciated....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ignore this error (if you are sure of what you are doing) with:

```
excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass();    
excel.DisplayAlerts = False
```

And restore the default behavior with:

```
excel.DisplayAlerts = True
```